# iFrame src something other than javascript:false but same effect

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-6

Is there any other way to write `javascript:false` that is more pleasant?

I'm building a print functionality for an intranet app (for IE6) and I make the printed page using an iframe:

```
$('body').append('<iframe id="printIFrame" src="javascript:false"></iframe>');
$("#printIFrame").attr('style','position:absolute;left:-500px;top:-500px;');
```

Without having `javascript:false` in the src, I'll get the "This page contains both secure and nonsecure items" popup when I create it. However the downside of this is that "javascript:false" gets printed as the title on the bottom left of each page (instead of about:blank or something more useful).

Is there some kind of javascript technique that I can write `javascript:false` but in cleaner terms? I tried something like this

```
var PrintOut = false;
$('body').append('<iframe id="printIFrame" src="PrintOut"></iframe>');
```

But I couldn't get that working. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a "/blank.do" or something from the same server (or origin, rather) as (temporary?) src for your iframe. Then you should not get the "insecure" stuff.
Why do you want/need it to be done by javascript?

Comment: this is causing the browser to do unwanted requests, which depending on case could have performance implications.

Answer (score 1):

How about an existing, but empty, resource using the same protocol?

```
<iframe id="printIFrame" src="https://example.com/empty.html"></iframe>
```

You could, to make it perfect, even have `empty.html` send a `204 No Content` header to signify it's empty. (Info [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html))

Comment: I think you meant status 204, right?  That's "no content"; 402 is "payment required".

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid unwanted requests you have to use `<iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>`