# iframe without an src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, src

I would like to create an `<iframe>` on the page, but then add the `src` later. If I make an iframe without an `src` attribute, then it loads the current page in some browsers. What is the correct value to set for the `src` so that it just loads a blank iframe?

The answers I've seen are:

- `about:blank`
- `javascript:false`
- `javascript:void(0)`
- `javascript:"";`
- url to a blank page

Is there a clear winner? If not, what are the tradeoffs?

I'd like to not have mixed content warnings for HTTPS urls, nor any back-button, history, or reload weirdness in all browsers from IE6 onward.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iFrame src something other than javascript:false but same effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503648/iframe-src-something-other-than-javascriptfalse-but-same-effect)

Comment: You could create the iframe at the moment you have the src available, to avoid this issue. Would that work?

Comment: That question was asking for prettier way to write "javascript:false". I don't care how ugly the line is, I want the functionality. And the accepted answer was a url to a blank page which pays an HTTP round-trip which seems worse than being able to avoid that.

Comment: @Ioannis no, it is a long story, but assume I need the iframe on the page, then the url will be populated later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard approach when creating an "empty" iframe (as an iframe shim, for example), is to set the src as `javascript:false;`. This is the method used by most of the JavaScript libraries that create iframe shims for you (e.g. YUI's Overlay).

Comment: Yes, in IE9-10 iframe writes text "javascript:false;". In this case it's better to check and use src="" if not IE or if IE > 9. For IE9 - well, bad luck. PS "javascript:'';" works everywhere but calls onload twice in some browsers.

Comment: This may work in all browsers but will break if a website does not allow inline javascript in their `Content-Security-Policy` header. Therefore please don't use this in scripts that you expect other parties to include in their sites.

Comment: I agree w/@LeighMcCulloch.  I've enabled CSP and `javascript:false` is being reported as an unsafe script-src directive when using Facebook SDK.  (I believe that `about:blank` may be the preferred method to use.)

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if all browsers support "about:blank", so I'd just go with your own blank page then.

Another idea: Why not add the whole iframe using javascript instead of just the src?

Comment: For your first answer, that pays an unnecessary HTTP round trip, which seems sub-optimal.

Comment: @Paul but the second answer is spot on if you're planning to populate the iframe using js

Comment: For your second answer, I'm populating the iframe with form submit. So I want the iframe on the page, and then the <form> sets the src.

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
about:blank
```

Comment: Tested in IE7,8(+quirks mode), FF3.6, Opera 10.63, Safari 5, Chrome 7.0.x - About:blank presents the most consistent behavior.

Comment: It's not part of a standard though so, like `javascript:`, you can't rely on *every* client interpreting it correctly

Comment: Mostly good testing. Still missing IE 6, FF 3, Safari 4, Chrome 5 and Chrome 6. And could OS matter here?

Comment: What about [Konqueror](http://www.konqueror.org/features/browser.php), @IoannisKaradimas? My point is, if it's not in the standard, you can't assume that every user will see it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Re your comment clarifying that you're planning to use the iframe as the target for a form submission:

I would use an empty document on the server that sends back a `204 no content`.

It avoids

- "mixed content" warnings in IE and HTTPS mode
- Unnecessary errors because a client doesn't understand the `javascript:` protocol
- and other exotic shenanigans.

It's also valid HTML.

So what if it generates an extra request? Set the caching headers right, and there will be only one request for each client.

Comment: The empty document is a possibility but I would much prefer to avoid it if possible. One less thing to maintain. If the community can provide a solution that does everything the empty document does AND doesn't require the extra file, that is strictly better in my mind.

Comment: @Paul I agree, such a solution would be perfect. But I have seen this question a number of times on SO, and it never came up. The best there seems to be is `about:blank` which works in most browsers

Comment: Adding the 204 status code will not trigger the `onload` event to be fired on the iframe in some browsers, so this may not be the best approach if someone is looking to hook into that event.

Answer (score 3):

`javascript:false`:
IE10 and FF (checked in v23 in Linux) will show 'false' as content.

`javascript:void(0)` && `javascript:;`:
IE will show 'cannot display the webpage' error in the iframe. Also, when setting the src from a valid url to `javascript:void(0)`, the page will not get blank.

`about:blank`:
Works in all browsers but IE 9 sends an request to the server with path "null". Still the best bet IMO

Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/eybDj/1
Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/sv_in/gRU3V/ to see how iframe src changes on dynamic updation with JS

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:false` works in modern browsers.

What I've seen is that this only "fails" when dumb spiders try to load `javascript:false` as a page.

Solution: Block the dumb spiders.

Comment: There will always be more dumb spiders, though.

Comment: This may work in all browsers but will break if a website does not allow inline javascript in their `Content-Security-Policy` header. Therefore please don't use this in scripts that you expect other parties to include in their sites.

Answer (score 1):

As I posted in this question: [Is an empty iframe src valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946607/is-an-empty-iframe-src-valid/8823732#8823732), it looks acceptable to just leave out the `src=` attribute completely.

Answer (score 0):

IMO: if you don't put the src, your page won't validate. But's about it.
If you put a src="", your server will log many 404 errors.

Nothing is really wrong  as in "damaging". But then, is it actually not wrong to use an iframe in itself?

°-

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know I'm reviving an old thread. Sue me. I'm interested in the answer.

I don't understand why having the trigger being a form submit precludes dynamically creating the IFrame. Does this not do exactly what you want?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setIFrame(elemName, target, width, height) {
    document.getElementById(elemName).innerHTML="<iframe width="+width+" height="+height+" src='"+target+"'></iframe>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="iframe" style="width:400px; height:200px"></div>
<form onSubmit="setIFrame('iframe', 'http://www.google.com', 400, 200); return false;">
<input type="submit" value="Set IFrame"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP has stated that the iframe must be created some time before its `src` will be known (see comment history to the question itself).

Comment: Don't apologise for answering old questions.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this line of code:

```
iframe.setAttribute("src", "javascript:false");
```

as well. I wanted to remove `javascript:URL`.

Found this note from the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group [Updated 2 October 2019]

[https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-iframe-element][4.8.5_The_iframe_element]

> The otherwise steps for iframe or frame elements are as follows:
>
> If the element has no src attribute specified, or its value is the
>   empty string, let url be the URL "about:blank".