# Getting error after adding nonce instead of unsafe-inline'

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, nonce

I have below code in my xyz.js file.

```
init : function() {
   if (!this.iframe) {
       this.iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
       this.iframe.src = "javascript:false;";
       document.body.appendChild(this.iframe);
```

and I have update the code from unsafe-inline to nonce
in above code i am calling  `document.body.appendChild(this.iframe);`

and getting below error

> 1683098036010:402 Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present

I have tried to add nonce as below but it's not working

```
this.iframe.nonce = "EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa";
this.iframe.script='nonce="EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa"';
this.iframe.script.nonce="EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa";
this.iframe.setAttribute('nonce', "EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa");
```

As in code i have set this.iframe.src = "javascript:false;"; this should not throw that error.

can anyone please provide the update on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in  `this.iframe.src = "javascript:false;";`.
I have updated this line to `this.iframe.src = "about:blank;";`

For more please refer
[iframe without an src attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284605/iframe-without-an-src-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

For the `nonce` attribute you should set it on the script tag rather than the iframe. Then append the script tag to the body of the iframe's content document.

```
init: function() {
   if (!this.iframe) {
       this.iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
       this.iframe.src = "javascript:false;";
       document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
           document.body.appendChild(this.iframe);
       }.bind(this));
   }

   // Set nonce attribute on the script tag
   var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
   scriptTag.setAttribute("nonce", "EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa");
   scriptTag.textContent = ''; // write your js code here

   // Append the script tag inside the iframe content
   this.iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
}
```

Comment: but my error is coming in  document.body.appendChild(this.iframe); this line, it's not going down.

Comment: It's because the script is being executed before the document.body element is fully loaded. Edited the answer, have a try.

Comment: getting below error. caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'body')
    at YAHOO.Adeptra.ProgressIndicator.init (adeptra.js?_=1683528863919:419:31)
    at adeptraInit (adeptra.js?_=1683528863919:1727:16)
    at n (utilities.js?_=1683528863919:13:7981)
in this   line  this.iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(scriptTag);

Comment: @SakibRahman `this.iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(scriptTag);` is giving error as I see that `this.iframe` is null.  I think `this.iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(scriptTag);` is getting executed before `this.iframe = document.createElement("iframe");` Hence `this.iframe` is null and when we do `this.iframe.something` it is giving Cannot read properties of null. How can we make this code as synchronizable so that code execution happens one line at a time?